# Finding upper cutoff and lower cutoff frequencies on notch circuit

Tags: filter, frequency, passive-networks, telecommunications, cutoff-frequency

I need to find upper cutoff (UCF) and lower cutoff (LCF) frequencies based on formulas of a notch circuit, but I'm getting a quadratic equation (as expected) with an imaginary number (IN; not expected.)

I tried to solve this equation transforming the IN to polar coordinates then cutting off the angle (which gave me f'=2MHz and f''=2,57MHz, values very far from what was expected - something around fo.)

How can I find these frequencies?

This is the circuit I've been working on.

[image]

This is the formula I used to find UCF and LCF. (Which are represented by f in the formula.)

[image]

Some values I have already found:

- Zp:21256ohms
- Rp:123000ohm
- Qp:70ohm
- fo=2,269MHz

The roots of the formula fo will be the lower cutoff frequency and the upper cutoff frequency.

I also tried to solve this by calculating the bandwidth (BW), then

- UFC=fo+BW/2
- LFC=fo+BW/2
  Other formulas I used can be found on this photo:

[image: this photo]

Comment: You need to ask a question and not repeat what you might write in your diary. This is a Q and A site and you need to concentrate on the Q bit.

Comment: It looks ok but far better to make a 4th order notch at this Q.   http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$+0+0.000005+5+50+5+46%0A%25+0+92193520.0325712%0Aw+288+208+336+208+0%0Aw+336+208+384+208+0%0Aw+288+128+336+128+0%0Aw+336+128+384+128+0%0Al+288+128+288+176+0+0.00009999999999999999+0.0015019953469635006%0Ac+384+128+384+208+0+4.5e-11+0%0Ar+336+240+336+208+0+12300%0AO+384+208+480+208+0%0Ag+336+240+336+256+0%0A170+288+128+256+128+3+10+150+5+0.5%0Ar+288+176+288+208+0+70%0Ao+9+128+0+34+5+0.00009765625+0+-1%0Ao+7+128+0+34+5+0.00009765625+1+-1%0A

Comment: Change any parameter you wish.   Http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$+0+0.000005+5+50+5+50%0A%25+0+92193520.0325712%0Ar+368+144+368+320+0+500%0A170+224+144+192+144+2+20+4000+5+0.1%0AO+368+144+432+144+0%0Aw+224+96+224+144+0%0Aw+304+96+304+144+0%0Ag+304+320+304+336+0%0Ag+368+320+368+336+0%0Ac+224+144+304+144+0+1.0709642115135004e-9+0%0Ac+304+240+304+320+0+6.1248411356639885e-12+0%0Al+224+96+304+96+0+0.000004593630877368796+0.03907158777844048%0Al+304+144+304+240+0+0.0008032231631150725+-0.0027039273953149037%0AB+224+16+304+416+1+Box%0Aw+304+144+368+144+0%0A

Comment: Keep in mind Q>=100 makes LC tolerances impossible to achieve in 2nd order, and easier in higher order filters, also keep in mind the Falstad  screen resolution is a clue to change spectrum BW and filter design sensitivity, these are emitter follower or Op Amp driven with any load.you cannot buy /afford 0.1% tolerance LC parts

Comment: Do you know to find the upper and lower cutoff frequencies with the formula given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's about calculating the bandwidth, it would be better to calculate the transfer function instead of relying on pre-made formulas:

$$\begin{align}
Z_{ser}(s)&=R_{ser}+sL\tag{1} \\
Z_{par}(s)&=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{Z_{ser}}+sC}\tag{2} \\
H(s)&=\frac{R}{R+Z_{par}(s)} \\
&\Rightarrow \\
H(s)&=\frac{RLCs^2+RR_{ser}Cs+R}{RLCs^2+(RR_{ser}C+L)s+R_{ser}+R} \\
{}&=\frac{s^2+\frac{R_{ser}}{L}s+\frac{1}{LC}}{s^2+\left(\frac{R_{ser}}{L}+\frac{1}{RC}\right)s+\frac{R_{ser}+R}{R}\frac{1}{LC}}\tag{3}
\end{align}$$

This gives a transfer function in the generic form:

$$G(s)=K\frac{s^2+\frac{\omega_z}{Q_z}s+\omega_z^2}{s^2+\frac{\omega_p}{Q_p}s+\omega_p^2}=K\frac{s^2+BW_zs+\omega_z^2}{s^2+BW_ps+\omega_p^2}\tag{4}$$

From \$(3)\$ and \$(4)\$ the center frequency and the bandwidths can be extracted:

$$\begin{align}
K=H(0)&=\frac{R}{R+R_{ser}}\tag{5} \\
\omega_p=\omega_z&=\frac{1}{LC}\tag{6} \\
BW_z&=\frac{R_{ser}}{L}\tag{7} \\
BW_p&=\frac{R_{ser}}{L}+\frac{1}{RC}\tag{8} \\
\end{align}$$

Which shows that the formulas in your post discard the \$R_{ser}\$ element and, for small enough values it can be discarded. In this case: \$25\;\Omega\$ and \$15\;\text{k}\Omega\$, so it's fine. To verify use a calculator or simulator to compare the circuit with the Laplace expression:

[image: test]

The RLC version overlaps with the Laplace expression, so it's a match. The measured quantities are the frequencies, `f1` and `f2`, the passband bandwidth `bw`, and the center frequency, `fc`, against the calculated `bwp` and `f0`. The numbers come very close, save precision, parasitics, etc.

---

Given your formulation I'm not sure how to interpret your question, but I'll add this, to be sure. In case what you want is to find independent formulas for \$f_L\$ and \$f_H\$, then all you have to do is use the following system of equations:

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
f_Hf_L&=\frac{1}{LC} \\
f_H-f_L&=\frac{R_{ser}}{L}+\frac{1}{RC} \\
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

which results in a 2nd order equations with the two valid roots:

$$f_L=\frac{\sqrt{(RR_{ser}C)^2+2RLC(R_{ser}+2R)+L^2}-RR_{ser}C-L}{2RLC} \\
f_H=\frac{\sqrt{(RR_{ser}C)^2+2RLC(R_{ser}+2R)+L^2}+RR_{ser}C+L}{2RLC}$$

And the result of the `.meas` scripts are:

```
f1: freq=(2.36937e+006,0) at 2.36937e+006
f2: freq=(2.66826e+006,0) at 2.66826e+006
f_lo: (sqrt(c**2*r**2*rs**2+2*c*l*r*rs+4*c*l*r**2+l**2)-c*r*rs-l)/(2*c*l*r)/2/pi=(2.36856e+006,0)
f_hi: (sqrt(c**2*r**2*rs**2+2*c*l*r*rs+4*c*l*r**2+l**2)+c*r*rs+l)/(2*c*l*r)/2/pi=(2.6736e+006,0)
```